# JNDI - how to use a file embedded in a JAR, WAR, or EAR to use in the provider URL?

Tags: java, url, log4j2, jndi, ear

I'm using log4j2 to log messages to a system via JMS/MQ.  I used IBM MQ Explorer to create a .bindings file in my local C:\JNDI-Directory folder.  This works great when running locally, but when I deploy to WebSphere, I would like to be able to bundle my .bindings file with my EAR.  The appender in my log4j2.xml looks like:

```
<JMS name="jmsQueue"
         destinationBindingName="AuditDest"
         factoryName="com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory"
         providerURL="file:/C:/JNDI-Directory"
         factoryBindingName="JMSConnectionFactory">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%m"/>
    </JMS>
```

My deploy environment is WebSphere Application Server running on AIX.  I will have several environments I'm deploying to (i.e. Dev, Test, QA, Stage, Production) and in my build I would like to use an environment specific .bindings file based on the one I created locally as only the queue manager name and IP will change for each environment.

So I thought I could put the .bindings file in a properties folder and during the build for a deployed environment just copy dev.bindings to .bindings in the WAR or EAR archive.  However, I'm not certain how to construct the providerURL string.  If I just use "file:/properties/" on my local machine it gets interpreted as C:\properties instead of looking in my WAR or EAR MANIFEST.MF Class-Path.

Is it possible to do this, or will I have to request our WAS admins to create a .bindings file for each server?  I want to avoid this so I can more directly control things as requesting changes in our WAS environment will require a ticket, that requires lead time to complete, etc.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Haven't tested but you could try this syntax: `jar:file:/path/of/jar/somefile.jar!/path/inside/the/jar/file` or simply without any prefix: `/path/inside/the/jar/file` (or `path/inside/the/jar/file` -- the leading slash is mandatory in some contexts, forbidden in others)

Comment: My log4j2.xml is located in the JAR.  So I tried jar:file:/ since .bindings is at the top level of the JAR.  However, I get a malformed URL error for jar:file:/.  The JAR is at the top level of the EAR and is not external.